# How to RUN docker commands inside a folder

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker

How using a Dockerfile can I `RUN` all commands within a folder home?

For example, in Docker I have the following where I have to `CD` into the folder before running the second command:

```
RUN cd /var/sites/demo && virtualenv env --system-site-packages
RUN cd /var/sites/demo && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Is there a way I can remove the `cd /var/sites/demo` and have each command run from that location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting `WORKDIR` to the appropriate path:

From the [`Dockerfile Reference`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/):

> The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile.

So your file should have:

```
WORKDIR /var/sites/demo
```

Before your `RUN` commands.